# How can I make my WordPress Nav Links Show Up?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I was trying to replace the hamburger menu that is with this theme, I successfully removed the hamburger menu through editing the styles in the child theme. I added these code in my customizer but the my nav links doesn't show up. I wanted to make the nav links into a horizontal position just like the default menus. I would appreciate some help. Thank you! This is the code I added in my customizer:

```
@media screen and ( min-width: 1024px ) and (max-width: 1281px) {


.menu-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
  .site-logo {
    max-height: 100px;
  }
  .has-site-logo .main-navigation {
    height: 100px;
  }
  .has-site-logo .main-navigation > div,
  .has-site-logo .main-navigation > ul {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
  .main-navigation {
    font-size: 0.8125em;
    line-height: 2.09231em;
    clear: none;
    float: right;
    max-width: 50%;
    text-align: right;
  }
  .main-navigation ul:first-child {
      display: block;
  }
  .main-navigation ul li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .main-navigation ul li:hover > ul,
  .main-navigation ul li.focus > ul {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }
  .main-navigation ul a {
    border-bottom: 0;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 14px;
  }
  .main-navigation ul ul {
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    display: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    float: left;
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 0 7px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 27px;
    left: 0;
    text-align: left;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 99999;
  }
  .main-navigation ul ul li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    padding: 5px 5px 4px;
  }
  .main-navigation ul ul li:last-of-type {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
  .main-navigation ul ul li a {
    line-height: 1.5;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 180px;
  }
  .main-navigation ul ul ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
  }
  .main-navigation ul ul li a,
  .main-navigation ul ul ul li a,
  .main-navigation ul ul ul ul li a {
    padding-left: 5px;
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

This is how it looks like when I added the code. The hamburger disappears but my navs links won't show up and horizontally. I'm using the default Wordpress theme Scrawl for testing purposes.

Comment: Please also provide the markup that these classes target. There is no way to truly answer your question without knowing that structure. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What is the HTML code for the nav? Please update your question with it.

Comment: I just went to the site and look for the html structure and it seems that I didn't find any ul or li links on the nav menu.

Comment: your `.menu-toggle` still `display:none`

Comment: Okay, if I remove the display none, how can I replace the hamburger icon menu to a horizontal nav menu?